# boostrap selected menu item resets after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, repeater

I am using boostrap to create a tabbed menu inside an asp.net web application.

I am using a couple of repeaters to set up the menu items as well as the content of tabbed pages. There are only two tabbed items, with values set from DB. The issue I am struggling with is that after a postback, selected menu goes back to first menu item. Initially I show the first tab using conditional styling.

This is the tabbed menu:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptCategories">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills ">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li class="<%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "nav active" : "nav" %>">
            <a href='#<%# Eval("Abbrev")%>' data-toggle="tab">
                <h3><%# Eval("CourseCategory")%></h3>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<!-- Tab panes -->

<div class="tab-content">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptCategoryList" OnItemDataBound="rptCategoryList_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="<%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "tab-pane fade in active" : "tab-pane fade" %>" id='<%# Eval("Abbrev")%>'>
                <div class="container" style="margin-top: 25px;">
                    <h2 style="color: #0F4194;" class="text-center"><%# Eval("CourseCategory")%></h2>
                    <div class="row">
                        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptCourses" OnItemDataBound="rptCourses_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptCourses_ItemCommand">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="bronze panel panel-default ">
                                        <div class="bronze panel-body">
                                            <h4 class="text-center"><asp:Label runat="server" id="lblCourseName" Text='<%# Eval("CourseName")%>' /></h4>
                                            <p class="text-justify">
                                                <%# Eval("CourseDesc")%>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbViewVideo" runat="server" 
                                                CausesValidation="False"    
                                                CommandName="AddCourse" 
                                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("AUCourseID") %>' 
                                                data-URL = '<%#Eval("CourseURL")%>' 
                                                data-CourseID = '<%#Eval("AUCourseID")%>'
                                                data-CourseName = '<%#Eval("CourseName")%>'>
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></i> View the  Tutorial
                                            </asp:LinkButton>
                                         </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

I can select second menu item with list of courses. As soon as I click on the linkbutton to view the video (i.e. a postback) first menu gets selected. I can see that it is because menu style is based on Container.ItemIndex being 0 or not (style is "nav" or "nav active") but not sure how to get around it.

Comment: use updatepanel.

Comment: That was the very first I tried when I ran into this issue. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bootstrap-Tabs-Maintain-Selected-Active-Tab-on-PostBack-in-ASPNet.aspx)

I had to add a hidden field that kept track of selected menu (selected Category, in my case). Then used jQuery to get the value of hidden field; if it was empty , select default/first menu, otherwise use that value to select the menu. Also, within same script, associate an onclick event to menu items.

In code-behind, one line of code sets hidden is fetched from request.Form.

This is what I ended up with:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfSelCat" runat="server" />

<div class="container">
    <div id="divCategories">
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptCategories">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills ">
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </ul>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                    <a href='#<%# Eval("Abbrev")%>' data-toggle="tab" aria-controls='<%# Eval("Abbrev")%>' >
                        <h3><%# Eval("CourseCategory")%></h3>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var tabName = $("[id*=hfSelCat]").val() != "" ? $("[id*=hfSelCat]").val() : "DelOps";
        $('#divCategories a[href="#' + tabName + '"]').tab('show');

        $("#divCategories a").click(function () {
            $("[id*=hfSelCat]").val($(this).attr("href").replace("#", ""));
        });
    });
</script>
```

In code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ...
        hfSelCat.Value = Request.Form[hfSelCat.UniqueID];
    }
}
```